# SQL Data Load On ASP.net Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, sql-server-2014, portal

We have a custom website portal that was developed using ASP.net, C# and MS SQL Server. When a user logs in he sees data on different pages depending on the ID he uses to log in with.

The portal works fine and is quick enough apart from data loading, this is where the problem lies.

One of the pages reads data from SQL that has normal columns as well Binary data as well. One of the users who logs in picks up about 400 rows of data, which usually isn't much but for some reason takes a very long time to load (2 maybe 3 minutes at most).

Today when the user clicked on the page it basically kicks the user out, however normal users with little data to load could still browse the page. After some troubleshooting i picked up that once I restarted SQL Services on the database server the user who had an issue worked fine again, page took some time to load but still worked fine after restarted the SQL Services.

Any idea what on SQL could be causing this? Or is there some buffer or cache size that needs to be increased to allow for a speedier data load?

Comment: Show how you are taking the data. That could be causing the delay.

Comment: Depends on your query (joining tables? A View?) and how your displaying this data (GridView/Repeater/etc?).  Without some code to go on there are far too many possibilities as to what the problem could be. First thought is; are the tabled Indexed properly?

Comment: this could be an issue related to not closed connections, are you sure you are closing all the connections to sql server?

Comment: Thanks guys for the helpful comments, the problem was actually lying in the query which was going across 3 tables and had a lot of rows. Much quicker now..

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that you need update the statistics.  Here is a good [article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/02/bad-statistics-reason-query-slow/) that explains how to check if the statistics are causing the slow down.